# Keeping nested prototype methods from object transfering from WebWorker

Tags: javascript, typescript, web-worker

I need to reserialize an object from a WebWorker sharing the same definitions.

Upon reception of the message, I'm losing all the prototype functions.

Doing

```
worker.onmessage = ({ data }) => {
    this.programParser = Object.assign(new ProgramModel(), data);
}
```

Works only for first level prototype functions, but I need a solution for all the nested classes (this object has a large inheritance and dependency tree).

What could I do to do that ?

Current data model looks like :

[image]

(note the `Object` prototypes)

Using flatted and custom revive function (I added the class name in each object from the serializing function), I can achieve a much closer model to what I would need, but some nested references aren't treated as original class objects.

[image]

The flatted revive function is the following :

```
const model = parse(data, (key, val) => {
  if (val !== null && val.className && val.className in models) {
    if (val.className === "DataProvider") {
       console.log(val)
       return new DataProvider(val.providerData)
    }
    return Object.assign(new (<any>models)[val.className](), val)
   }
   return val;
 })
```

The flatted library is used to keep clear of circular issues of JSON serialization : https://github.com/WebReflection/flatted

Minimal exemple of the issue : https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-https-n314w?file=/src/index.ts (Object is lost after 2nd level referencing)

Comment: You can use lodash, `cloneDeep` - https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep, what you are doing over there with Object.assign is a shallow copy, not a deep one.

You can also do a deep copy using `const deepCopied = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));`

Comment: I'm slightly confused as to the constraints of the problem ... do you control the worker? Can you modify the class `ProgramModel`?

Comment: I can modify the ProgramModel and control the worker.

Comment: I am currently trying to work with the flatten module as I have some circular issues with my data model

Comment: @NicolaeMaties will those options conserve all prototype functions? To be clear, the output of my worker has the shape of ProgramModel but strips off all prototype functions and I need a way to revive them.

Comment: Then the obvious solution would be for the worker to `postMessage` not a `ProgramModel` instance, but the data needed to properly construct a `ProgramModel` (possibly with a special factory method), but I suppose there are reasons you can't do that...

Comment: Indeed, the object has a lot of nested references and we would have to rewrite the serializing function everytime a change occurs.

Comment: I'm curious, maybe someone has a very smart solution, but I'm not very hopeful since methods don't pass the structured clone algorithm and you certainly don't want `eval`-equivalent ones.

Comment: I could try a solution using `eval`, but I'm afraid the object being transfered would end up weighing a LOT hence killing the performance (as this is supposed to be an optimization procedure in our code). I am currently considering passing the class name upon serialization to be used to revive all the nested objects using that parameter.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you mean about the prototype methods not being maintained. You are using already the ProgramModel class in your worker, which comes with it's prototype tree. What are you missing out on? Could you perhaps provide a code example of what you are loosing?

Comment: Are you trying to do multiple inheritance, from both data's class and ProgramModel's?

Comment: I updated my question, is it clearer?

Comment: I thought about the possibility to implicitly cast objects automatically when accessing them from the `ProgramModel` object. For example, wouldn't it be possible to cast `programModel.sections[0]` from an object to a `SectionModel` by overriding base accessors? I could be doing so by checking the `className` property and cast if this exists and is available.

Comment: "*some nested references aren't treated as original class objects.*" - can you clarify what this means and also add a [mcve] for it, please? You also mention "*I have some circular issues with my data model*" and "*the object has a lot of nested references and we would have to rewrite the serializing function everytime a change occurs*" but without giving a concrete example what to doesn't work.

Comment: "*Using flatted and custom revive function*" - what is that? If you refer to a library there, please link it - should we assume that this `parse` function is coming from elsewhere? Also please add the code that serialises your model.

Comment: I updated the question, there's no serializing code for the model besides the `stringify` method of the flatted library. I just add `.constructor.name` property of objects to rebuild them on the main process side using reflection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't want to take any credit from [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70087692/2800218), but while the explanation/process through is nice and sound, I believe the proposed solution is not the best one, and btw, I am the author of the flatted library that actually explained, and helped out, in [this issue](https://github.com/WebReflection/flatted/issues/52#issuecomment-977613021) filed against such library, without even knowing there was a discussion here ... sorry I am late ...

The missing piece of the previous answer is that the same instance gets updated over and over while reviving the whole structure, but nothing like that is actually needed, because either `Set` or `WeakSet` can help speeding up the process, avoiding upgrading what's been upgraded already, over and over.

```js
const {setPrototypeOf} = Reflect;
const upgraded = new Set;
const ret = parse(str, (_, v) => {
  if (v && v.className && models[v.className] && !upgraded.has(v)) {
    upgraded.add(v);
    setPrototypeOf(v, models[v.className].prototype);
  }
  return v;
});
```

This change doesn't strictly improve the reason it either works or it is the best solution, compared to substitution, but it takes into account performance and redundant upgrades, 'cause unnecessary `setPrototypeOf` calls, might not be desired at all

Comment: "*avoiding upgrading what's been upgraded already*" - uh, does the flatted library call the reviver function multiple times on the same object? It really shouldn't, in my understanding.

Comment: Flatted reviver does exactly what JSON reviver does, and because of recursion, the same object can be passed along in any path that's being revived. If a reviver is tracking paths or parent objects per path and want to do something special with a recurring reference, thay can ... if the reviver plays a "too smart role", they cannot. So yes, flatted reviver does what JSON reviver does, and if recursion is involved, it's reflected, at any depth in the reviving operation. The same goes for stringifying.

Comment: Oh, right, because the reviver is getting called on each *property* (including the top-level `""` one), not on each value. However, do you really think that an unnecessary `setPrototypeOf` call (that doesn't actually change the prototype) is that much slower than a set lookup?

Comment: Beside the fact that *yes*, `setPrototypeOf` is slower than `set.has(ref)`, it's about correctness of the operation. Here we are only upgrading the prototype, but if there was any other procedure involved to revive an instance, i.e. needing to invoke some getter or setter to validate the internal state, having the same instance upgraded more than once will be just wasteful and error prone. That's why my answer is better, because it scales with other more complex cases with ease, and it is more correct than the other one.

Comment: To expand slightly more: recursion exists because the same reference can be literally everywhere. That means that while the `set.has(ref)` could be a set of a single, recurrent, entry, for many different objects, `setPrototypeOf` there could happen thousand times for no benefit or reason whatsoever. I hope these last two explanations are sound. Take care 

Comment: I wouldn't say one is more correct than the other, since we *are* only upgrading the prototype. More complex cases would need a different evaluation. But I've updated my answer to avoid repeated `setPrototype` calls anyway :-) And I don't think you can validate anything inside the reviver, since when the reviver is called for the first time some objects are still incomplete. I'd rather put everything into a `Set`, then iterate that to validate the instances *after* all circular references are set up.

Comment: that's also one way to go, and `set.add(instance)` is also faster than many upgrades, but as one that wrote polyfills for Web components since 2014, I can assure you reviving with more than just a prototype upgrade is, in certain situation, a common procedure, and avoiding that circle more than once per entity that needed an upgrade, is not just mandatory, but disaster prone if done differently ;-) Thanks for updating your answer too though.

Comment: P.S. just noticed you used getPrototypeOf instead of a set ... that's still slower than my solution, but at least it confines needed upgrades 

Answer (score 1):

This is a classical problem with [tying the knot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/357956/1048572) on a circular structure. When deserialising, the *flatted* library has to start somewhere, passing in the original not-yet-revived object as the argument. It could in theory pass a proxy (or an object with getters) that parse the involved objects on-demand in the right order, but if all objects in the circle need to be revived this would lead to a stack overflow, as JS doesn't use lazy evaluation where you can reference the result of a call before having evaluated it.

A pure approach would actually need a reviver function that does support such a lazy approach, not accessing the object passed to it until after the deserialisation has finished:

```
const cache = new WeakMap();
const ret = parse(str, (k, v) => {
  if (cache.has(v)) return cache.get(v);
  if (v && v.className && (<any>models)[v.className]) {
    const instance = new (<any>models)[v.className]();
    cache.set(v, instance);
    for (const p in instance) {
      Object.defineProperty(instance, p, {
        set(x) { v[p] = x; }, // not necessary if your models were immutable
        get() { return v[p]; },
        enumerable: true,
      });
    }
    return instance;
  }
  return v;
});
```

This essentially makes the `instance` a proxy over `v`, getting all its values from there. When *flatted* does tie the knot by assigning revived values to properties of `v`, they'll also become available on `instance`. Apart from the `.className`, no properties of `v` are accessed during the reviver call. Only when you access `ret.something`, the object properties will be read, and will contain the revived objects by then.

The downside of this approach is that a) all models will need to declare and initialise their properties upfront (which your `B` for example doesn't do) so that the `for (const p in instance)` loop works, and b) all your model properties will be replaced with accessors, which is inefficient and may conflict with the internal implementation.

An alternative is to forward the property assignments that *flatted* does on the original object to the newly constructed instance, even if they happen after the reviver call:

```
const cache = new WeakMap();
const ret = parse(str, (k, v) => {
  if (cache.has(v)) return cache.get(v);
  if (v && v.className && (<any>models)[v.className]) {
    const instance = new (<any>models)[v.className]();
    cache.set(v, instance);
    Object.assign(instance, v);
    for (const p in v) {
      Object.defineProperty(v, p, {
        set(x) { instance[p] = x; },
        get() { return instance[p]; }, // not truly necessary but helps when `v` is logged
      });
    }
    return instance;
  }
  return v;
});
```

This basically reflects how you originally constructed the circular reference using `a.setB(new B(a))`, except by directly assigning the property instead of using the model's `setB` method, which the reviver doesn't know about. When using this approach, make sure to explicitly document that all your models must support constructor calls without arguments, and direct property assignment (be it via `Object.assign` or `instance[p] = x`). If setters are necessary, use accessor properties (`set` syntax) instead of `set…()` methods.

The simplest and probably fastest approach would be to not return a new object from the reviver at all, but keep its identity:

```
const ret = parse(str, (k, v) => {
  if (v && v.className) {
    const model = (<any>models)[v.className];
    if (model && Object.getPrototypeOf(v) != model.prototype) {
      Object.setPrototypeOf(v, model.prototype);
    }
  }
  return v;
});
```

This restores the prototype methods by simply swapping out the prototype of the revived object for the expected one. However, this means that your models are instantiated without a constructor call, they may not use enumerable getters, and they cannot maintain private state even if they expose it through `.toJSON` correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your quality answer. So far, only the last option works in my case, but with a huge processing time (almost as long as the one I tried to put in a WebWorker). Is there a way to improve its efficiency?

Comment: Your second solution strips pretty much all information from my object : https://paste.pics/4b6054c65474c8563adeda24dc154501

Comment: This will be accepted as answer, more information can be found on https://github.com/WebReflection/flatted/issues/52.

Comment: @MaximeB I had not realised that the reviver would get called multiple times on the same object, the first and second snippet were broken for that reason. I missed that while toying around with them they would create multiple equal-looking objects (without forming an actual circular reference), not one and the same object. Fixed now.